# magento1.9 get login event with observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, login

I'm trying to use observers 
My goal is to do something after successful login
I wrote this but I think I don't understand something...
What's wrong?
app/etc/modules/Drg_Customeraccess.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Drg_Customeraccess>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Drg_Customeraccess>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Drg/Customeraccess/etc/config.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <Drg_Customeraccess>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Drg_Customeraccess/observer</class>
            <method>customerLogin</method>
        </Drg_Customeraccess>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

app/code/local/Drg/Customeraccess/Model/observer.php

```
<?php
class Drg_Customeraccess_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        if ($customer){
        echo "nameOBS-".$customer->getFirstname();
        }


    }
}
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/code/local/Drg/Customeraccess/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Drg_Customeraccess>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Drg_Customeraccess>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <drg_customeraccess>
                <class>Drg_Customeraccess_Model</class>
            </drg_customeraccess>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <drg_customeraccess_login>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>drg_customeraccess/observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </drg_customeraccess_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Drg/Customeraccess/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Drg_Customeraccess_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if ($customer)
        {
            echo "nameOBS-".$customer->getFirstname();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Prince ...can you tell me if the observer is correct to to print customer info like name, mail etc???

if ($customer){
        echo "nameOBS-".$customer->getFirstname();
        }

Comment: look my update please

Comment: `Observer.php` is in uppercase

Comment: now after login it goes to homepage and not to account page but I can't see  "nameOBS" nowhere in code or printed on screen

Comment: Try this and tell me what you see `<?php
class Drg_Customeraccess_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        die('testttttt');
        }
    }
}
?>`

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: you oberserver is not working, please check carrefuly all the files according my answer

Comment: are you declared the module in `app/etc/modules` ?

Comment: yes. the file is called Drg_Customeraccess.xml and contains
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Drg_Customeraccess>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Drg_Customeraccess>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: please share your full etc/config.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<global>
    <models>
        <Drg_Customeraccess>
            <class>Drg_Customeraccess_Model</class>
        </Drg_Customeraccess>
    </models>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <drg_customeraccess_login>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Drg_Customeraccess/observer</class> 
                    <method>customerLogin</method>
                </drg_customeraccess_login>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>
</frontend>

Comment: you have many mistakes, look again my config.xml

Comment: something hjappened!!
works with die"test" but with nameOBS return a magento error :
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/magentotest/public_html/app/code/local/Drg/Customeraccess/Model/Observer.php, line 8
This is line 8:
 echo "nameOBS-".$customer->getFirstname();

Comment: ouuf, good now your observer works, for the error, try replace this line with : var_dump($customer);

Comment: now print customer information for a second then show the same error

Comment: You have all the customer informations ?

Comment: only firsname , lastname and email are required and I need to push it in a datalayer  like:
 <script type="text/javascript">
dataLayer.push({
 'nome': '<?php echo $customer->getFirstname() ?>',
 'cognome': '<?php echo $customer->getLastname() ?>',
 'email': '<?php echo $customer->getEmail() ?>'
     });
</script>

Comment: ok, so where is a problem ?you have your informations and your observer works

Comment: I still have the error

Comment: if you just put this you still have the error ?: `public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        
    }`

Comment: Please accecpt the answer if it has been helpfull, Good luck

Comment: I'm here sorry.
can I write you a private message?
config.xml and Observer.php are exactly like your answer but the error still appear.
to see the error you can try to login in our test site
https://magento.sg.drgiorgini.it/customer/account/login/
test@test.it
test123